# Creating a new column based on a conditional and a count by group

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements

I have a dataset as follows:

```
DT <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22), Household = c(1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 
13), Main = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), Variable = c(0.298830253959918, 0.696637114803799, 
0.222731978341587, 0.641245156419456, 0.145562076370066, 0.191365477844148, 
0.881263670583021, 0.314050677064662, 0.0770074657918196, 0.299236771626852, 
0.872886923047494, 0.289628283880055, 0.270138675264831, 0.910147226969786, 
0.582434831286225, 0.791627720726525, 0.852872802843926, 0.599723929185799, 
0.558087460306338, 0.862531226564633, 0.361200983684113, 0.765999001124532
)), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

[image]

To this dataset I want to add an extra column. If there are more than two `ID`'s per `Household`, I want the `Variable` values of the `Household` members who have `Main==0` summed and added to as a new variable, to the rows of the `Household` members who have `Main==1` AND VICE VERSA. If there is no other `Household` member, the value is `0`. I would preferably do this in `data.table`, but I get stuck quite quickly. I started out as follows:

```
# create a var with the nr of hh members
DTattempt <- setDT(DT)[, count:= .N, by=Household]

# if there is only 1 hh member, the value of New_Var = 0
DTattempt <- setDT(DTattempt)[count == 1, New_Var:= 0, by=Household]

# Now I try to fill in the value for the other rows, but here I get stuck
# I do not know how to tell R that it should only sum the other variables
DTattempt <- setDT(DTattempt)[count > 1, New_Var:=  ifelse(Main==1, sum(Variable, by=Household), sum(Variable, by=Household), by=Household]
```

Desired result:

```
DTnew <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22), Household = c(1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 
13), Main = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), Variable = c(0.29883025, 0.69663711, 0.22273198, 
0.64124516, 0.14556208, 0.19136548, 0.88126367, 0.31405068, 0.07700747, 
0.29923677, 0.87288692, 0.28962828, 0.27013868, 0.91014723, 0.58243483, 
0.79162772, 0.8528728, 0.59972393, 0.55808746, 0.86253123, 0.36120098, 
0.765999), New_Var = c(0.91936909, 0.29883025, 0.29883025, 0.14556208, 
0.64124516, 0.88126367, 0.19136548, 0.07700747, 0.31405068, 0, 
0, 0, 0.91014723, 0.27013868, 0, 0, 0, 0.55808746, 0.59972393, 
0.36120098, 1.62853023, 0.36120098)), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next works:

```r
setDT(DT)
DT[, nm := .N, by = .(Household, Main)]
    [, newVar := sum(Variable), by = .(Household, Main)]
    [, New_Var := sum(newVar/nm) - newVar, by = .(Household)]
    [, c("nm", "newVar") := list(NULL,NULL)]
    ID Household Main   Variable    New_Var
 1:  1         1    1 0.29883025 0.91936909
 2:  2         1    0 0.69663711 0.29883025
 3:  3         1    0 0.22273198 0.29883025
 4:  4         2    0 0.64124516 0.14556208
 5:  5         2    1 0.14556208 0.64124516
 6:  6         3    1 0.19136548 0.88126367
 7:  7         3    0 0.88126367 0.19136548
 8:  8         4    1 0.31405068 0.07700747
 9:  9         4    0 0.07700747 0.31405068
10: 10         5    0 0.29923677 0.00000000
11: 11         6    1 0.87288692 0.00000000
12: 12         7    1 0.28962828 0.00000000
13: 13         8    1 0.27013868 0.91014723
14: 14         8    0 0.91014723 0.27013868
15: 15         9    1 0.58243483 0.00000000
16: 16        10    1 0.79162772 0.00000000
17: 17        11    1 0.85287280 0.00000000
18: 18        12    0 0.59972393 0.55808746
19: 19        12    1 0.55808746 0.59972393
20: 20        13    0 0.86253123 0.36120098
21: 21        13    1 0.36120098 1.62853023
22: 22        13    0 0.76599900 0.36120098
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very cool way of solving it with that third line.

Comment: Indeed a fantastic way!

Answer (score 2):

I know my solution may not be perfect but it should work

```
library(tidyverse)

DT2 <- DT %>% arrange(Household, Main) %>%
  mutate(new = ifelse(Main == 0, as.complex(0+1i), 1)) %>%
  group_by(Household) %>%
  mutate(new = sum(new*Variable)) %>%
  group_by(Household, Main) %>%
  mutate(new = ifelse(Main == 1, Im(new), Re(new))) %>%
  ungroup() %>% arrange(ID)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Accepted the other answer for being slightly less complicated and being a data.table solution. One small comment, for the answer line 10 is supposed to be zero (because the Household has only one member).

Comment: Oh! In that case it is easier.  I'll edit the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: For interchanging values, I used complex numbers which can be treated as two dimensional numbers